# Is there an easier way to pattern match this function?

Tags: haskell

Building a function that takes boolean values for X and Y and returns the boolean value of the proposition. It should work as follows

```
>eval False False ((X :->: Y) :&: (Not Y :|: X))
True
>eval False True  ((X :->: Y) :&: (Not Y :|: X))
False
>eval True  False ((X :->: Y) :&: (Not Y :|: X))
False
>eval True  True  ((X :->: Y) :&: (Not Y :|: X))
True
```

The only way I can think to solve is to pattern match for every possibility (as below) but surely there is a better way to do this?

```
eval a b (X :|: Y) = a || b
eval a b (X :&: Y) = a && b
eval a b (X :->: Y) = not a || b
eval False False (X :|: X) = ...
eval False False (X :|: Tr) = ....
eval False False (X :|: Fa) = False
eval False False (X :|: Not _) = ...
eval False False (X :|: _ :&: _) = ...
eval False False (X :|: _ :|: _) = ...
eval False False (X :|: _ :->: _) = ...
eval False True (X :|: X) = ...
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there's a better way.

```
eval a b (e :->: e') = ...
eval a b (e :|: e') = ...
eval a b (e :&: e') = ...
eval a b (Not e) = ...
eval a b Tr = ...
eval a b Fa = ...
eval a b X = ...
eval a b Y = ...
```

Fill in the dots, and you're all the way done. If you find the repetition of `eval a b` annoying, you can use a `case`:

```
eval a b expr = case expr of
    e :->: e' -> ...
    e :|: e' -> ...
    -- etc.
```

Comment: You can shorten that even further with `LambdaCase`